# Windows Phone 7.5 Calendar live tile

Tags: tiles, calendars

My Windows Phone 7.5 calendar has two calendars that I have synced to the device.  One calendar is mine and the other is my wife's calendar.

I would like to be able to see both calendars in the calendar app but only show my calendar information in the live tile and on the lock screen.

I have searched the settings of the phone but cannot find what I am looking for.  Is there a setting that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not control which calendars show information on live tile or lock screen. All calendars are treated equal, and as such any entry from any calendar is displayed.

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid of that.  Do you know if WP8 will support this?

Comment: @wbeard52 There has been no announcement about this. my guess (and that's all it is) is that nothing will change. sorry :(